# Swift iOS CVCalendar: Change the initial displayed month

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `CVCalendar` with `presentation mode = .monthView`. The calendar is all up and running and working correctly. I want to be able to set the initial month view to a different month (it currently always displays the current month).

I have tried doing this by setting `CVCalendarView.presentedDate` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    thisCalendarView.presentedDate = aFutureDate
    updateTitleText()
}
```

The `.presentedDate` variable is updated, but I still see the current month view displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `thisCalendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()`

Comment: Hi Jake, thankyou for the suggestion, unfortunately I am still seeing the same result.